# I get HTTPError: Not Found exception when I open the url

Tags: python, url, browser, urllib2

I would like to get the information on this page：
http://www.jnfdc.gov.cn/onsaling/viewhouse.shtml?fmid=757e06e0-c5b3-4384-9a14-2cb1eac011d1

From the browser debugger tools I get the information in this file：
http://www.jnfdc.gov.cn/r/house/757e06e0-c5b3-4384-9a14-2cb1eac011d1_154810896.xml

But when I use the browser to access the url directly, I can't get the file.

I don't know why.

I use python.

```
import urllib2

#url1 = 'http://www.jnfdc.gov.cn/onsaling/viewhouse.shtml?fmid=757e06e0-c5b3-4384-9a14-2cb1eac011d1'
url = 'http://www.jnfdc.gov.cn/r/house/757e06e0-c5b3-4384-9a14-2cb1eac011d1_113649432.xml'
headers = {
    "Accept" :"*/*",
    "Accept-Encoding" :"gzip, deflate, sdch",
    "Accept-Language" :"zh-CN,zh;q=0.8",
    "Cache-Control" :"max-age=0",
    "Connection" :"keep-alive",
    "Cookie" :"JSESSIONID=A205D8D7B0807FD34F879D6CB6EEB0CE",
    "DNT" :"1",
    "Host" :"www.jnfdc.gov.cn",
    "Referer" :"http://www.jnfdc.gov.cn/onsaling/viewhouse.shtml?fmid=757e06e0-c5b3-4384-9a14-2cb1eac011d1",
    "User-Agent" :"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.104 Safari/537.36 Core/1.53.3051.400 QQBrowser/9.6.11301.400"
    }

req = urllib2.Request(url, headers=headers)

resp = urllib2.urlopen(req) #this code throw exception:HTTPError: Not Found
```

How could I do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For getting data from browser you can try to use Selenium - [Selenium doc](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)